# How to use Mathematica MathPDE Package?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, packages

I'm trying to use the Package MathPDE that is introduced here http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2011/12/mathpde-a-package-to-solve-pdes-by-finite-differences/.

Since I could not find anything about the version of mathematica that is needed to use the package it always says:

> "Get::noopen: Cannot open  `` MathPDE` ``." and "Needs:nocont: "Context "`` MathPDE` ``" was not created when Needs was evaluated.".

I tried

```
Needs["MathPDE`"];
```

Thanks for any help.
Dan

Comment: That is not a standard package.  It isn't included with any version of Mathematica.  It's up to you to find it.  Yes, it's annoying when people write a paper about a package and they don't say where you can get the package.

Comment: I had to look this up as it said **mathematica journal**.  If it is a wolfram thing, it is perhaps not a bad idea to drop the folks at wolfram a line on this.  Note that I did try this once but received absolutely no reply when requesting information about a package.

Comment: I wrote the author an email that he answered very rapidly with the following link.

https://openmodelica.org/openmodelicaworld/applications/category/5-openmodelica-scripts

You can find the Math PDE package there but its not working. If your try to get the example work (I recommend replace SetDirectory["E:\MathPDE"];  by SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]; in the example file) you will get errors. Maybe I or someone else will get it to work.

Comment: If you go to the menu item Cell > Notebook history... you can see when changes were made to the notebook.  From that I would guess it was developed in version 8, possibly earlier (though you can probably use it in later versions, it is likely bugs will occur).

Comment: I'm using mathematica version 8. Since the file says in one comment "begin 2004" it is possibly mathematica 5 or earlier.